# place 2 components in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

In this component, I have an image at the top and then 2 other components (inside `<ItemsContainer/>`) at the bottom that appear as different rows. I want to put the other two items (a grid and a chart) in a single row and I have already tried using flex direction but it does not seem to work for me. It could be happening because I am using `flex-direction: column;` in the parent component already.

```
    <main className='content'>
    <img src={poly} alt="charts" className="charts" />
    <div className="heading">
    Heading Text
    </div>
    <span> The he text goes here. </span>
  <div className="regressionSetup">
    <ItemsContainer/>
    </div>
      </main>
```

```
.content{
    padding-left: 260px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
}

.popup{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.charts{
    align-self: center;
    height: 350px;
    width: 800px;
}

.heading{
    font-size: 25px;

}

.regressionSetup{
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

[image]

ItemsContainer:

```
        return(
            <div className="container">
            <PointDrawer addCoord={this.addCoord.bind(this)} 
                resetCoords={this.resetCoords.bind(this)}/>
            <RegressionSetup
                order_graph_1={this.state.order_graph_1}
                order_graph_2={this.state.order_graph_2}
                setOrders={(orders: any) => this.setState(orders)}
            />
            <Graph x={this.state.x_array} y={this.state.y_array} 
                deg={this.state.order_graph_1} width={800} 
                color={this.color_graph_1} />
</div>)
```

css

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
```

How can I fix this such that the grid appears on the left and the chart appears on the right but in the same line/row?

Comment: try adding style="width=50vw"; on both your components inside itemscontainer

Comment: that did not seem to work. I added the code for the components as well @RaishavHanspal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap. So column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, [if you want 2 equal-width columns across, you can use .col-6.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

The code would look like this of `ItemContainer`:

```
<div className="container-fluid pt-4">
    <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-6">
            <PointDrawer addCoord={this.addCoord.bind(this)} 
                resetCoords={this.resetCoords.bind(this)}/>
            <RegressionSetup
                order_graph_1={this.state.order_graph_1}
                order_graph_2={this.state.order_graph_2}
                setOrders={(orders: any) => this.setState(orders)}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
            <Graph x={this.state.x_array} y={this.state.y_array} 
                deg={this.state.order_graph_1} width={800} 
                color={this.color_graph_1} />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are using simple CSS, then let's try to use `display: flex`:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container .item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
```

So you code would look like this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="item" >
      <PointDraweraddCoord={this.addCoord.bind(this)} resetCoords={this.resetCoords.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <RegressionSetup order_graph_1={this.state.order_graph_1} order_graph_2={this.state.order_graph_2}
        setOrders={(orders: any)=> this.setState(orders)}
        />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: that doesn't make a difference for me. I changed it to normal css (updated code too). Added red bg to check only. Can you suggest anything now?

Comment: @Jbd could you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gwoJZk) example?